# How to create a functioning multipage streamlit app?

Tags: python, web, streamlit

I am creating a web app using Streamlit. I have created a multipage app where the sidebar has a drop-down menu to go to a particular page. I have created a page that allows the user to input a sequence and count the number of characters (for example a DNA sequence and count the number of nucleotide bases). The architecture of my web app is as follows:

```
Web_App
|
|__app.py (main file)
|__multipage.py
|__home.py
|
|__apps (another folder)
   |__nucleotide_eda.py
```

The problem that I am facing right now is when I run the streamlit keeping the sequence page (nucleotide.py) as the home page (meaning just running the sequence page) the inbuilt calculations in the nucleotide.py is running fine (the user submits the query sequence and automatically the A/T/G/C counts are given along with a bar plot). But when I add the nucleotide.py as a multipage and run my main file (app.py) the inbuilt functions are not working. I only see the text box area where the user can give the input sequence.

I have given it multiple tries but still, the problem persists. My code looks like this:

app.py (main file):

```
import streamlit as st
from multiapp import MultiApp
from apps import home,nucleotide_eda 

app = MultiApp()

# Add all your applications here
app.add_app("Home", home.app)
app.add_app("Nucleotide EDA", nucleotide_eda.app)
app.run()
```

Nucleotide.py (sequence file):

```
import streamlit as st

def app():
    st.title('Exploratory Data Analysis of Genomic Sequence')
    
    st.write('Nucleotide EDA allows you to perform Exploratory Data Analysis on any submitted genomic sequence')
    
    st.header("Enter Your DNA Sequence in FASTA Format")
    
    sequence_input = ">DNA\nATGCGCTAGGATACA"
    
    sequence = st.text_area("Sequence Input", sequence_input, height=250)
    sequence = sequence.splitlines()
    sequence = sequence[1:]
    sequence = ''.join(sequence)
    
    st.write('''***''')
    
    st.header("Input Query Sequence")
    sequence
    
    st.write('''***''')
    
    st.header("Nucleotide Count") 

    def nucleotide_count(seq):
        d = dict([('A', seq.count("A")),('T',seq.count("T")),('G',seq.count("G")),('C',seq.count("C"))])
        return d
    
    X = nucleotide_count(sequence)
    X_label = list(X)
    X_values = list(X.values())

    X
    st.write('''***''')
```

All I see is the text box prompting the user to give input. But once a sequence is submitted nothing happens. I expect that once a user submits the sequence, the web app should first print the input query using:

```
st.header("Input Query Sequence")
sequence
```

and then runs the "nucleotide_count" function and gives out the corresponding dictionary.
Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use st.write().

```
   st.header("Input Query Sequence")
   st.write(sequence)  # <----------------------------------- this
   
   st.write('''***''')
   
   st.header("Nucleotide Count") 
   def nucleotide_count(seq):
       d = dict([('A', seq.count("A")),('T',seq.count("T")),('G',seq.count("G")),('C',seq.count("C"))])
       return d
   
   X = nucleotide_count(sequence)
   X_label = list(X)
   X_values = list(X.values())
   st.write(X)  # <----------------------------------- this
   st.write('''***''')
```

#### Sample output

[image]